# Custom Android Cordova Plugin

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am trying to create a customized Android plugin for a Cordova application. I seem to be missing something that is not calling `androidalert.alert()`

Creating plugin:

```
plugman create --name AndroidAlert --plugin_id cordova-androidalert --plugin_version 0.0.1`
```

`plugman createpackagejson AndroidAlert`

Add source file to src/android/AndroidAlert.java:

```
package com.example.plugin;
import org.apache.cordova.*;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

public class AndroidAlert extends CordovaPlugin {

  @Override
  public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
    if ("alert".equals(action)) {
        callbackContext.success();
        return true;
    }
    return false;  // Returning false results in a "MethodNotFound" error.
  }
}
```

Add class and method to www/AndroidAlert.js:

```
var exec = require('cordova/exec');

exports.alert = function(arg0, success, error) {
    exec(success, error, "AndroidAlert", "alert", [arg0]);
};
```

Add plugin.xml platform and edit clobbers:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<plugin id="cordova-androidalert" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <name>AndroidAlert</name>
    <js-module name="AndroidAlert" src="www/AndroidAlert.js">
        <clobbers target="androidalert" />
    </js-module>
    <platform name="android">
        <config-file target="config.xml" parent="/*">
            <feature name="Alert">
                <param name="android-package" value="com.androidalert.Alert"/>
            </feature>
        </config-file>
        <source-file src="src/android/AndroidAlert.java" target-dir="src/com/androidalert/" />
    </platform>
</plugin>
```

Add android platform:

```
cordova platform add android
```

Add plugin:

```
cordova plugin add ../AndroidAlert
```

Add to Cordova application in www/js/index.js:

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
        this.receivedEvent('deviceready');
        //navigator.notification.alert("Water", function() {}, "ERROR", "Okay");
        var success = function(message) {
          alert(message);
        }
        var failure = function() {
          alert("Error calling Hello Plugin");
        }
        androidalert.alert("World", success, failure);
    }
```

Run in emulator:

```
cordova emulate android
```

Comment: Try connecting Chrome DevTools to the Webview to check for errors and add breakpoints, and do the same for the Java using Android Studio (by opening `platforms/android`).

Comment: @DaveAlden I am getting a "Unable to determine Android SDK directory." when I go to open the Android project in the `platforms/android` directory. Any idea why?